# Android: Integration of git Repository in eclipse says that set the HOME variable?

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipselink, eclipse-cdt

I am going to set the repository for the development of my Eclipse Android Project. I have follow all the steps currectly from [here:](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html#eclipseinstallation)

But after doing that i got the error while going to share the existng project.
See the image below:

[image]

So Whats the Solution for it ?
Please help me for that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HOME is an environmental variable in your operating system.

In Windows:

- Right click "My computer" and select "properties".
- On the "System" screen click "Advanced System Settings".
- On the "System properties" click "Environmental Variables"
- Then add click "New" and enter "Home" for `name` and the path of a directory you want to use as your home directory in `value`.